# bash - How to store files outside working directory in variables

Tags: bash

I need to store a file outside my working directory into a variable in my bash script. I can store a file in the same directory just like this :

```
value1 = 'File4'
```

But if I want to get access to files outside my directory, do I have to use `cd` to get to that directory first?

Comment: Not with the spaces in `value1 = 'File4'` you can't.

Answer (score 2):

You may either access your files by absolute path, i.e. `/home/user/path/to/my/file.txt` or by relative path: `../another_directory_at_the_same_level/file.txt`. Double dots mean a super-directory, i.e. if your working path is `/home/user/working/path`, then `../` will be `/home/user/working`.

Comment: Recommend surrounding the paths in single quotes

Answer (score 2):

First you will need to calculate the current directory (where the script is executing from) then you will be able to access any directory via its  relative path . like this =>  `$curr_dir/../$value1` or  `$curr_dir/../../$value2`..etc

Here is how you get the current directoy .

`curr_dir=$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))`

`$0` =>> currently runing script .. the script where `value1 = 'File4'` is declared

`readlink -f` pass `$0` as an argument to resolve any symlinks.

`dirname` to remove the file from the returned full path.